# How to iterate over MultivaluedMap and extract the key and its corresponding first value?

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

Here is my code its my first attempt . But what is the correct way to do this.

```
    private Map<String,String> prepareParameters(MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParameters) {

    Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String,String>();
    for (Map.Entry<String,List<String>> e : queryParameters.entrySet()) {
        parameters.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue().get(0));
    }
```

Comment: Map is not ordered. Please note :) Get ready for surprises.

Comment: But the List is. The values of the keys in the Map are List of String. I may be wrong feel free to correct me.

Comment: But each time you'll get a different List as you don't know which is at place one. Making sense ?

Comment: What I want is that this method should return a map of key and its corresponding first value. I know there is a method getFirst() in MultivaluedMap. How to use it here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One way to do this can be :--

```
  private Map<String,String> prepareParameters(MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParameters) {

   Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String,String>();

   Iterator<String> it = queryParameters.keySet().iterator();


         while(it.hasNext()){
           String theKey = (String)it.next();
           parameters.put(theKey,queryParameters.getFirst(theKey));
       }

   return parameters;

    }
```

OR without using the iterator, as suggested by Dinei Rockenbach, we can do as follow:-

```
  private Map<String,String> prepareParameters(MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParameters) {

   Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String,String>();

   for(String str : queryParameters.keySet()){
     parameters.put(str, queryParameters.getFirst(str));
   }
   return parameters;

    }
```

Comment: One could simply use `for(String theKey : queryParameters.keySet()) { ... }` instead of working directly with `Iterator`.

Answer (score 2):

Or using streams...

```
queryParameters.getRequestHeaders().entrySet().stream()
.collect(
    Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> entry.getValue().stream().findFirst().orElse(null)));
```